# How to use styled-components in react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Total newbie on using `styled-components`. I'm wondering what's the usage of it? How should I implement component life cycle methods after styling it? For simplicity sake I've removed all the other style.

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: 'green'
`

export default Button;
```

I'm wondering how do I further working on this `Button` component?

Traditionally we can declare a class-based component and implement some lifecycle methods, but now with this `styled-components`, I'm not really sure how to combine them together as they are really the single `Button` Component?

**UPDATES:**

Full sourcecode for `Button.js`. By having the below code, all styles will be gone and I can't understand the problem

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
// import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

import color from '../config/color';

const Button = ({ children, onPress }) => (
  <button type="button" onPress={onPress}>{children}</button>
);

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  width: 12rem;
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: ${(props) => {
    if (props.inverted) return 'white';
    if (props.disabled) return color.disabled;
    return (props.color || color.primary);
  }};
  color: ${(props) => {
    if (props.disabled) return color.disabledText;
    if (props.inverted) return (props.color || color.primary);
    return 'white';
  }};
  border:${(props) => (props.inverted ? `2px solid ${props.color || color.primary}` : 'none')};
  border-radius: 60px;

  &:hover {
    filter: ${(props) => (props.inverted || props.disabled ? 'none' : 'brightness(95%)')}
  }
`;

export default StyledButton;
```

Comment: Hmmm.. What do you want to do with the styled button in this component?

Comment: @wentjun: I guess I am not quite understanding the concept..Traditionally I would define `Button` component in `Button.js`. I'm thinking to use `styled-components` to just style it?

Comment: You can use it like any other component..! Let me write up an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to style a custom react component you can pass on the custom component name as argument to `styled`. According to the doc:

> The styled method works perfectly on all of your own or any
>   third-party component, as long as they attach the passed className
>   prop to a DOM element.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
// import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

import color from '../config/color';

const Button = ({ children, className onPress }) => (
  <button type="button" className={className} onPress={onPress}>{children}</button>
);

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  width: 12rem;
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: ${(props) => {
    if (props.inverted) return 'white';
    if (props.disabled) return color.disabled;
    return (props.color || color.primary);
  }};
  color: ${(props) => {
    if (props.disabled) return color.disabledText;
    if (props.inverted) return (props.color || color.primary);
    return 'white';
  }};
  border:${(props) => (props.inverted ? `2px solid ${props.color || color.primary}` : 'none')};
  border-radius: 60px;

  &:hover {
    filter: ${(props) => (props.inverted || props.disabled ? 'none' : 'brightness(95%)')}
  }
`;

export default StyledButton;
```

Read the [`styled-component documentation`](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component) for more details on styling any component

Comment: Thanks for answering, I had the exact similar thoughts when I read the docs but I failed to implement it. Can you take a look at my updated code and see which part has gone wrong? Coz the style is gone once I implemented like this

Comment: @issac, you need to pass on a classsName to DOM element you want to style. According to doc :`The styled method works perfectly on all of your own or any third-party component, as long as they attach the passed className prop to a DOM element.`

Answer (score 2):

Let's rename the styled button component to reduce confusion between the 2 similarly named components.

styled-button.tsx:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background-color: 'green'
`

export default StyledButton;
```

When you import the styled button component into your `Button` component, you can actually use make use of it the way you usually do when you are working with traditional HTML `<button>` elements, as its props are exposed and available on the styled component as well.

button.tsx:

```
import StyledButton from './StyledButton'

class Button extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { someProps, otherProps } = this.props;
    // some lifecycle logic
  }

  handleClick() {
     // do the rest
  }

  render() {
    return <StyledButton onClick={() = this.handleClick()} />;
  }
}
```

If you want, you can even pass in props from the parent `Button` component, to the child `StyledButton` component. This will allow you to customise it.

```
render() {
  const { color } = this.props;

  return <StyledButton background={color} onClick={() = this.handleClick()} />;
}
```

And on your StyledButton component, you just need to make the following changes:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background-color: ${({ color }) => color || 'green'}
`
```

Answer (score 2):

What other answers lack is for styling custom components like `Button` you have to pass a `className` prop thought it.

The styling is [injected through `className` property](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components).

```
const ButtonDefaultStyle = styled.button`
  width: 5rem;
`;

const Button = ({ className, children, onPress }) => (
  <ButtonDefaultStyle className={className} type="button" onPress={onPress}>
    {children}
  </ButtonDefaultStyle>
);

export default Button;
```

Then the styles can be applied:

```
import Button from './Button.js'

// Will override width: 5rem;
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  width: 12rem;
`;
```